# DRY principle on audio processing block

Tags: c++, audio, design-patterns, architecture

In my audio processing code (audio processor) I have something like below code. I am trying to avoid this below repetitive code. Wondering if there is any better way to write this code?

Code is just an illustration to understand the problem: I have several audio processing blocks where the audio of one block is passed as input to second block and so on until the final processed output. There are 4 major components of this 'blocks': Initialization, processing, reset, and de-initilzation.

```
    /* some code here to initialize audio processing blocks */
    //snip

    /*
     * order of audio processing is important here.
     * Is there any way to avoid writing below code
     * for every processing block that gets added in
     * future in c++11 perhaps??
     */
    if (t1) {
        t1->process(iFrame, oFrame);
        iFrame = oFrame;
    }
    if (t2) {
        t2->reset();
        t2->process(iFrame, oFrame);
        iFrame = oFrame;
    }
    if (t3) {
        t3->process(iFrame, oFrame);
        iFrame = oFrame;
    }
    /* 
     * if in future we want this way t1 - > t3 - > t2 then code change is required, 
     * is there any way to avoid this code change
     */
```

In essence I am looking for a generic way to handle this:

*P*1 -> *P*2 -> *P*3 -> *P*4

1. At compile time we should be able to define the order of processing blocks. Initialize the blocks with values read from a configuration file.
2. After that the process function is called for each of them and final output is produced.
3. During the processing some blocks can have reset function and other callbacks based on the processing blocks.
4. After the processing is done, we need to de-initialize the blocks.
5. How do we pass output of first block to input of second block and so on.

*P* stands for processing block.

https://ideone.com/GEvaKm

Comment: Why is only `t2` reset?

Comment: @Quentin: all processing blocks doesn't need reset before processing.

Comment: If you're fine accomodating that with an empty `reset` function in these blocks, a base class and virtual functions should fit your needs nicely. You can then store them in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseProcess>>` and call them in order.

Comment: @Quentin: agreed, how about passing output of first block to second one and also the order can change?

Comment: You just have to keep the `iFrame = oFrame` line to pass data along. Reordering the blocks would be done by just reordering the vector.

Comment: @Quentin: if you can put that as an answer, will accept that after waiting for a response.